# using cp in shell script function () does not work

Tags: shell-script, function

mkdir works fine but it does not copy (doesn't throw an error either).

```
#!/bin/sh

copy_function() {

if $1 $2 $3 $4;then
    echo "copied directory and contents"
else
    echo "failed"
    exit 1
fi
}

copy_function mkdir -p ~/TestFolder/TestFile/
copy_function cp -pr my_data/* /TestFolder/TestFile/
```

Comment: You should [learn Bash properly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).  Start by learning what shell globbing is.

Comment: im brand new to scripting. thank you. Trying to make a general function to make the script cleaner.  It has tons of repetitive stuff. If I get this to work, it would take away about 60 lines of repetitive code.

Comment: A shell *function* to create directories or to copy files is unnecessary.  For making directories, just make all the directories you want at once—one `mkdir -p` command with lots of arguments.  To reduce the copy commands, consider using `rsync`.

Comment: I have some very key, key "shell scripting how-to" posts (on this site) linked to from my profile page.  Start there.

Comment: did this change and it worked: copy_function cp "-pr" "my_data/*" "/TestFolder/TestFile/"

Comment: Honestly that's kind of a horrifying way to "fix" the script.  It reminds me of [the xkcd about workarounds](https://xkcd.com/763/).  The function is irreparably broken and if it actually does what you expect it will be mostly by coincidence or accident.  Sorry if that sounds harsh but it's an honest professional take on that code.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> copy_function() {
>
> if $1 $2 $3 $4;then
>     echo "copied directory and contents"
> else
>     echo "failed"
>     exit 1
> fi
> }
>
> copy_function mkdir -p ~/TestFolder/TestFile/
> copy_function cp -pr my_data/* /TestFolder/TestFile/
> ```

Let's deconstruct this function.  What does it actually do?

Firstly, it expects four arguments; if given more than that it will ignore all but the first four.

The line beginning with `if` means:

Subject the first four positional parameters (arguments received by this function) to [file glob expansion, followed by word splitting on white space,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) and then attempt to run the resulting line as a command (with the first word used as a command and the remainder passed as arguments to that command).

A better way to do this, using *all* positional parameters, and *not* subjecting them to an extra file glob expansion pass and word splitting, would be:

```
if "$@"; then
```

The next line outputs a message, "copied directory and contents".  The problem with this line is that it's misleading in the extreme—that's *not* what the function did.  The function did whatever was expressed in the first argument received.  If I were to run `copy_function rm -r -f ~`, I would *actually* be deleting my home directory—but I would get the output message, "copied directory and contents."  So this line is a lie.

The next two lines, `else` and `echo "failed"` are at least more accurate, since they don't try to say *what* failed.  Ideally error output would be delivered to standard error instead of standard out, though:

```
else
    echo failed >&2
```

The `exit 1` command might be okay for use in a script, if you really want your whole script to exit right at that point.  It might be better to use `return 1` instead, but this is a quibble.

The bigger problem is that **this entire function is totally pointless.**

There is absolutely *no use case for it ever.*

What does it do?  It:

1. Uses *some* (but not necessarily all) of its arguments,
2. Does file glob expansion and word splitting on those (which you probably didn't know about),
3. Runs them as a command, and
4. Prints a message which is *probably a lie* if the command succeeds, and
5. Prints a totally uninformative message "failed" if the command fails.

**NONE of this is useful functionality.**

The script could be shortened to just this:

```
mkdir -p ~/TestFolder
cp -vpR mydata ~/TestFolder/TestFile
```

This still has its own oddities, one of which is your transition from a home-directory-based path (`~/TestFolder`) to a root-directory-based path (`/TestFolder`), but I've fixed that.  An odder choice is the name `TestFile` for a *directory.*

But those aspects aside, note the `-v` switch to make the copy command *verbose.*

Also note that by copying the entire containing directory, rather than a glob expansion, hidden files (a.k.a. "dotfiles") will be copied regardless of the current setting of your shell's "dotglob" option.

---

A properly written shell script is *very* concise, and *very* powerful.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  Learn the features of the commands you're using before adding wrapper functions.

And please, read the [Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) if you plan to do any serious scripting.